# C# SMO Restore LogFile ToPointInTime Fail to find the time in Log

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I try to restore to Point in Time with SMO and had some difficulty.

I have a bak file at midnight that I restore with no recovery so my base stays in restore stat.
then I have transaction file every hour.
And I try to restore it one by one until a time I choose.
For this example, I chose 2 AM.

My code looks like this.

```
private void ExecuteTransactions() 
{            
   try            
   {                
      var restore_name = _targetDatabase.Name;
      Restore restore = new Restore();
      //Log File 1.                
      var trFile = _transactions[0];                
      var backupDeviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(trFile, DeviceType.File);
      restore.Devices.Add(backupDeviceItem);                
      restore.Database = restore_name;                
      //SQL Time String
      // 2018-02-08T02:00:00
      //C# Time String 
      // 08/02/2018 02:00:00
      restore.ToPointInTime = _time.ToString(); 
      restore.ReplaceDatabase = false;
      restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Log;
      restore.SqlRestoreAsync(_smoServer);
      restore.Wait();
      Transaction_Complete();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Logger.Error("Message : " + ex.Message);
   }
}

private void Transaction_Complete()
{
   _transactions.RemoveAt(0);
   if (_transactions.Count > 0)
      ExecuteTransactions();
   else
      SetDatabaseOnline();
}
```

And the restore is going but it feels like he never gets the stop date.

For every Log file, I got

"This backup set contains records that were logged before the designated point in time. The database is being left in the restoring state so that more roll forward can be performed."

And after all is performed I still had the database in restore mode. And it doesn't seem to have work.
If with the same file I use SQLManger UI to restore it generate this SQL code

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [dbinchy] FROM  DISK = N'E:\BAK\dbinchy_backup_2018_02_07_233054_4259669.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'dbinchy' TO N'E:\SQL\dbinchy.mdf',  MOVE N'dbinchy_log' TO N'F:\LOG\dbinchy_log.ldf',  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
RESTORE LOG [dbinchy] FROM  DISK = N'E:\BAK\dbinchy_backup_2018_02_08_010022_1417567.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
RESTORE LOG [dbinchy] FROM  DISK = N'E:\BAK\dbinchy_backup_2018_02_08_030029_4243932.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5,  STOPAT = N'2018-02-08T02:00:00'

GO
```

The LOG restore stop after the second FILE (while i have 5)

If I execute it, it gives

"This backup set contains records that were logged before the designated point in time. The database is being left in the restoring state so that more roll forward can be performed."

For the First log file

and then

90 percent processed.
100 percent processed.
Processed 0 pages for database 'dbinchy', file 'dbinchy' on file 1.
Processed 141 pages for database 'dbinchy', file 'dbinchy_log' on file 1.

No second time this message. So it works in SQL but in C# I got the message about a point of time multiple time.

What do I miss? Anybody had a working sample with log restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the time String was important I change the format of ToString and now it's work with this code.
I tweak a bit the code that calls that to only add Log file that was before my time so I don't try useless file.

```
    private void ExecuteTransactions()
    {
        try
        {
            var restore_name = _targetDatabase.Name;
            _sw.Restart();
            Restore restore = new Restore();
            var trFile = _transactions[0];
            var backupDeviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(trFile, DeviceType.File);
            restore.Devices.Add(backupDeviceItem);
            restore.Database = restore_name;                
            restore.ToPointInTime = _time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
            restore.ReplaceDatabase = false;
            restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Log;
            restore.PercentComplete += Restore_PercentComplete;
            restore.SqlRestoreAsync(_smoServer);
            restore.Information += Restore_Information;
            restore.Wait();
            Transaction_Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Message : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Transaction_Complete()
    {
        _transactions.RemoveAt(0);

        if (_transactions.Count > 0)
            ExecuteTransactions();
        else
            SetDatabaseOnline();
    }
```